# WPF Could not load type 'AA.HMIRE.UserControls.AAButtonStan' from assemby

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I created a class AAButtonStan that inhertits from Button and has two string properties.
I am trying to use it defining a new UserControl but I have 2 problems:

1. When I try to add a AAButtonStan I receive the following error that I am not able to solve:

[image: ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/riUyh.png]

2. When I try to use *Binding* I receive this other error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like you have not added a refrence to the assembly that contains your button to the project that uses this button. This should fix both errors.

Comment: Have you build the project? It could also be that you haven't build the project, which is why the currently referenced DLL is not containing the new type.